# How can Postgres extract parts of json, including arrays, into another JSON field?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to convince PostgreSQL 13 to pull out parts of a JSON field into another field, including a subset of properties within an array based on a discriminator (type) property. For example, given a `data` field containing:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": "a",
  "items": [
    { "size": "small", "color": "green" },
    { "size": "large", "color": "white" }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to generate `new_data` like this:

```json
{
  "items": [
    { "size": "small" },
    { "size": "large"}
  ]
}
```

`items` can contain any number of entries. I've tried variations of SQL something like:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET new_data = (
  CASE data->>'type'
    WHEN 'a' THEN
      json_build_object(
        'items', json_agg(json_array_elements(data->'items') - 'color')
      )
    ELSE
      null
  END
);
```

but I can't seem to get it working. In this case, I get:

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE
LINE 6:         'items', json_agg(json_array_elements(data->'items')...
```

I can get a set of items using `json_array_elements(data->'items')` and thought I could roll this up into a JSON array using `json_agg` and remove unwanted keys using the `-` operator. But now I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I'm guessing it's a case of [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK). I've got about a dozen different types each with slightly different rules for how `new_data` should look, which is why I'm trying to fit the value for `new_data` into a type-based CASE statement.

Any tips, hints, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to handle the set `json_array_elements()` returns in a subquery.

```
UPDATE my_table
       SET new_data = CASE
                        WHEN data->>'type' = 'a' THEN
                          (SELECT json_build_object('items',
                                                    json_agg(jae.item::jsonb - 'color'))
                                  FROM json_array_elements(data->'items') jae(item))
                      END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb4737e418488f941840e0b55a629c93)

Also note that `-` isn't defined for `json` only for `jsonb`. So unless your columns are actually `jsonb` you need a cast. And you don't need an explicit `... ELSE NULL ...` in a `CASE` expression, `NULL` is already the default value if no other value is specified in an `ELSE` branch.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't caught the `-` operator applied to only `jsonb` and not `json`. My columns _are_ `jsonb`, but I was troubleshooting in a temporary table and was using `json` for my fiddling. As soon as I saw your answer, I realized my mistake and got it working.